# Create JsonArray without key value

Tags: java, json, gson

Please help me create jSonArray without keys. It should looks like:

```
"main" : ["one", "two", "three"]
```

I have tried it with empty key value:

```
private String generate(String value) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

    jsonObject.addProperty("", value);
    jsonArray.add(jsonObject);

    return gson.toJson(jsonArray);
}
```

Result looks bad..

```
"main": "[
  {\"\":\
  "myString value\"}
]"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("one"));
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("two"));
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("three"));
obj.add("main", array);
```

Comment: does not found array.add method in org.json.JSONArray? Is there we need to add any library to achieve the same? Please reply ASAP.

Comment: Please look at the question and you'll find a hint. It's about gson library. So basically you need to add this library to your project. https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html - here you'll see add mehod

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("one"));
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("two"));
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("three"));

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.add("main", array);;

System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonObject));
```

which outputs:

```
{"main":["one","two","three"]}
```

Comment: how to send this request ?   `[{"iGuestId":["88","89"]},{"iUserId":"2"}]` please give solution for this

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is just to fill an array with primitive variables, to achieve that you have to change your code like this:

```
private String generate(String value) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    jsonArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(value));

    return gson.toJson(jsonArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.add("msg 1");
list.add("msg 2");
list.add("msg 3");
obj.put("", list);
```

You can use this to put an array without key.

Comment: i will just put lib file name  which you can add in project.